# Difference between RRRR and YYYY in Oracle?

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, date

I have a stored procedure written in Oracle. I'm using a where condition in which i'm comparing two dates. I have a strange problem where the procedure works from oracle perfectly and when run from asp.net it just returns 0. Please look below for the procedure

---

```
PROCEDURE SAMPLEPROC
(
    P_DATE IN VARCHAR2,
    P_COUNT OUT NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) INTO P_COUNT from dual where 
to_date(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy')=to_date(P_DATE,'dd-mm-yyyy');
END;
```

---

Now, when i run the above code with below input.

```
INPUT : 11-02-2014

OUTPUT FROM ORACLE  : COUNT=1
OUTPUT FROM ASP.NET : COUNT=0
```

---

Then, After wasting long time, My friend just changed the format of the date to dd-mm-rrrr as shown below

---

```
  SELECT count(*) INTO P_COUNT from dual where 
        to_date(sysdate,'dd-mm-rrrr')=to_date(P_DATE,'dd-mm-rrrr')
```

---

After making the changes when we run with the same Input as above

---

```
   INPUT : 11-02-2014

    OUTPUT FROM ORACLE  : COUNT=1
    OUTPUT FROM ASP.NET : COUNT=1
```

---

Why is it like this? Why is it behaving in this way when run from ASP.NET

Please someone give me a explanation for this?

---

Added: From ASP.NET my date will be always coming as 11-02-2014 ie DD-MM-YYYY format and its not a Date datatype. Its just a string. The same procedure works perfectly when running from ORACLE and when sent data from Asp.net it gives me 0. I debugged it I saw that the data coming from asp.net is perfectly the same which I pass from oracle when testing.

So, I just need an explanation why it could be like this when YYYY was replaced with RRRR
when,

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL;
AND
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-RRRR') FROM DUAL;
```

returns the same data '11-02-2014'

Comment: Yes. It's varchar. I will be sending the data in dd-mm-yyyy format always so, i cannot change it to Date type as my webserver and DB server might give me format issues.

Comment: SELECT count(*) INTO P_COUNT from dual where 
       trunc( sysdate) =to_date(P_DATE,'dd-mm-yyyy')

Comment: The problem is already solved. My question is why it worked properly when we added RRRR instead of YYYY

Comment: rrrr format is to consider year relative to current century. when you have all the four dogits of year, yyyy is better

Comment: check for your nls settings, as I mentioned in my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT count(*) INTO P_COUNT from dual where 
       trunc( sysdate) =to_date(P_DATE,'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

It has to be like this.
sysdate already returns a date.

I believe ur `nls_date_format` is different in your sqlplus and asp connection.

So, to_date(sydate) is attempt to work on some string.. which I guess is `mm-dd-yyyy` or `dd-mm-rr`(most probably)  and so there could be mismatch.

```
SELECT value
FROM   nls_session_parameters
WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
```

please run the above query in both places to catch the mismatch!

Comment: I tried this. but its returning null when tested with 'dd-mm-yyyy' so, i queried entire nls_session_parameters and found there is no format with this, instead it contains all with rrrr(dd-mon-rrrr) at the end.

Comment: Null will be returned only if input is null. you mean, you get an exception?

Comment: ok.. I got it.. its showing it as DD-Mon-RRRR. I don't have access to chat.

Comment: Okay.. it is always not advisable to use to_date() on sysdate.. because, oracle try to do implicit conversions. And that is the reason for your conflict!

Comment: Just a doubt, If i use a DateField=to_date(INPUT,'dd-mm-yyyy') will it work perfectly?

Comment: yes it will be correct.. what ever nls setting reside in connection/session.. provided. your input has to be in same format always.. Also to make sure. the datefield column doesnt have time element, add a trunc(datefield).

Comment: Oh, may be dont have access to chat.stackoverflow.com due to firewallor something!

Comment: @smilu let me know, if you face any more issues.

Comment: As i understand it might be the problem when I tried to convert a Date field again into a Date field, and another is my DB date is in RRRR format and im trying to use YYYY. Thats what i understand.

Comment: Yes, you are right...when you work with `TO_DATE(input)` , input should be a String Only.. Not a date. Always, specify the format explicitly.. and we should not allow oracle to assume the format as per `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. That way, it is same everywhere you run.

Comment: Let me change my query and test it. If it works ofcourse ill accept it.